# Can I reuse utensils after sterilising potting soil after cleaning it?

Tags: soil, potting-soil, growing-medium, heat, potting-mix

For sterilising cocopeat/garden soil/potting mixes, I am thinking of using a big vessel from the kitchen on a stove with water. My question is, will this vessel be usable for cooking if I clean it with detergent/utensil liquid soap thoroughly or would I keep it away from cooking because of health hazards (possible fungi, insects etc.)

Comment: Good luck, you just killed your soil life, but not to worry, you just need to add some composting bacteria and fungi back to it. You can reuse things when washed well.